# Format dynamic datetime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I apologize if this has been asked, I've just filtered through about 40 questions on this site and other sites about formatting dynamic datetime and have only seen answers for `date()` etc. The issue is that I am trying to format registration dates and last login dates for a member based system that currently is formatted as such: `2012-09-29 10:21:40` to `Sep 2012`but as this is dynamic data I am not sure how to do this. This information is pulled from the database as such, just for the sake of clarification:

```
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id='$id'");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $username = $row['username']; // Ignore
        $sign_up = $row["sign_up"];
        $last_login = $row["last_login"];
    }
```

Comment: To clarify I am trying to do this in php not in mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) doc says:

```
date('M Y', strtotime($row["sign_up"]));
```

Comment: Genius, and extremely simple. I appreciate that, the php docs were confusing me on how to echo it, but when i saw this I figured I'd set the variable like `$sign_up = date('M Y', strtotime($row["sign_up"]));
` and then just `echo $sign_up;` thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly, you wish to convert the DATETIME format to be displayed in PHP as something like `Sep 2012`. You may wish to look at [date](http://www.php.net/date) and [strtotime](http://www.php.net/strtotime) too in the PHP Manual.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id='$id'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $username = $row['username']; // Ignore
    $sign_up = $row["sign_up"];
    $last_login = $row["last_login"];
    $convert = strtotime($sign_up);
    $convert = date('M Y',$convert);
    echo $convert . '<br />'; // this should be in the format Sep 2012
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in PHP you must reformat the datetime from mysql youself:

```
$sign_up = date('M Y', strtototime($row["sign_up"]));    
$last_login = date('M Y', strtototime($row["last_login"]));
```